# Adding an optional Import statement

Tags: qml

In QML-only application (so no backend) I'd like to have an **optional** import of a javascript file. If the optional library is present then the user has extra functionalities.

A regular:

```
import "xyz.js" as SoloAnalyzer
```

fails if the library is not found.

A try/catch is not valid on import statements:

```
try {
import "xyz.js" as SoloAnalyzer
}
```

What are the other options ? Thanks.

IMPORTANT: I'm limited to these versions : QtQuick 2.9 and QtQuick.Controls 2.2

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way to do this. The best I've ever been able to achieve is using a QQmlFileSelector from the C++ side to load different versions of QML files for different conditions. But I know of know way to do it solely from QML.

Comment: Can you generate the QML before the program is compiled?  You could optionally load it then.

Comment: You can actually use a `Loader` and check the status, but you will have to write some proxy code to actually use the functions in your .js file, because imports are not exposed to the Loader